# Why doesn't my projectile move in my code?

Tags: game-maker

My projectile currently has a create event with the following code:

```
//move towards mouse
move_towards_point(mouse_x,mouse_y,30);
```

My main character has a glob left button event with the following code:

```
instance_create(0,0,main_shuriken);
```

For the output, the shuriken appears at the top left of the screen, and does not move. I've noticed that if I tick off physics world in the "rooms" category, my shuriken seems to work fine.

Why doesn't my projectile move with `move_towards_point` and `create_instance` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. You want your `main_shuriken` instance to appear at your main character's position, not the top-left corner of the screen. Just change your *Global Left Button* Event as follows:

```
instance_create(x,y,main_shuriken);
```

This way the `main_shuriken` will be created at your main character's position (formally `(x,y)` of the instance executing such code) instead of the room origin (`(0,0)`, which is an *absolute* position, and not *relative*).

Your shuriken moves as expected if you tick physics world off in your room for a simple reason. The function `move_towards_point()` sets the current instance `direction` variable according to the direction from the instance position (its `x` and `y`) and the `x` and `y` coordinates given as arguments; also, it sets the instance `speed` variable to the value you give as third argument. The physics functions interfere with these built-in variables, which means that if an instance is ticked as "uses physics", even if you set `speed` and `direction` to some values, they won't work because the Box2D physics engine uses separate variables to deal with motion and physics. As the [official documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/physics/index.html) states:

> The physics system replaces many of the normal instance functions...
>   for example, rather than set a speed and a direction for an instance,
>   if it has been declared as being a fully simulated physical body, you
>   would use a force or impulse to get it to move around in the game
>   world, or if it is not physics enabled you will need to set the x an y
>   positions yourself. This takes a bit of getting used to, so experiment
>   with the physics functions and get to know how everything works before
>   trying to integrate them into your project.

When you turn off physics world, built-in variables are responsible for an instance motion.